# SQL, SUM + CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case

I try to do this :

```
SELECT
  o.ID_DOSSIER,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID_TYPE IN ('0','1') THEN SUM(TTL * -1) END) - SUM(CASE WHEN ID_TYPE IN ('2','3') THEN SUM(TTL) END)
FROM
  ope o,actor a
WHERE o.ID_ACTION=a.ID_ACTION
GROUP BY o.ID_DOSSIER
```

ask me if you don't know what i'm trying to do,

in prog like

```
case 1 : ID_TYPE IN ('0','1') THEN TTL1 = TTL * -1
case 2 : ID_TYPE IN ('2','3') THEN TTL2 = TTL
```

And `TTL = TTL2 + TTL1`

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: _ask me if you dont know what im trying to do_ YOU should tell us what you are trying to do and **ask** for help

Comment: I think that you simply need: `SUM(CASE WHEN ID_TYPE IN ('0','1') THEN TTL * -1 WHEN ID_TYPE IN ('2','3') THEN TTL END)`

Comment: @Jules: please tell me what you are trying to do..

Comment: @trincot I don't know what you're trying to comment.

Comment: in php for example,

Comment: I'm confused... how can `TTL` be defined as `TTL1 + TTL2` if both of those values are derived from `TTL`?  The only possible case I can see this mathematically working is if `TTL1`, `TTL2`, and `TTL` are all `0`.  The requirement doesn't make any sense...

Comment: takes values from ttl first and after juste put new value into him to make a print after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Then, you cannot nest aggregation functions, so this should be sufficient:

```
SELECT o.ID_DOSSIER,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ID_TYPE IN ('0', '1') THEN TTL * -1
                WHEN ID_TYPE IN ('2', '3') THEN TTL
           END)
FROM ope o JOIN
     actor a
     ON o.ID_ACTION = a.ID_ACTION
GROUP BY o.ID_DOSSIER
```